# Proof of limit to infinity using epsilon-N method

Tags: calculus, epsilon-delta

I wanted to prove this: $\lim_{x\rightarrow c} f(x)g(x)= \infty$ when $\lim_{x\rightarrow c} f(x) = L (L>0)$ and $\lim_{x\rightarrow c} g(x) = \infty$ by using epsilon-N method.

I used two inequalities derived by using epsilon-delta and epsilon-N method on two limit conditions. I thought that by fixing L as $L>\epsilon>0$, I could make the form of $f(x)g(x)>K (K>0)$ using inequalities. Well I cannot derive that form, my result was always $K<0$. How can I prove this statement? Thank you.

Comment: Choose $\delta_1$ such that\begin{align}0\lt|x-c|\lt\delta_1&\implies|f(x)-L|\lt \frac{L}2\\&\implies f(x)\gt \frac{L}2\\\end{align}and choose $\delta_2$ such that$$0\lt|x-c|\lt\delta_2\implies g(x)\gt \frac{2K}{L}$$then we have, for $\delta=\min{(\delta_1,\delta_2)}$,$$0\lt|x-c|\lt\delta\implies f(x)g(x)\gt K$$

Comment: @PeterForeman Hello, Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $M>0$. Since $f(x)\to L$ id $x\to c$, there is $\delta_1 >0$ s.t. $$f(x)\geq \frac{L}{2}>0,$$
whenever $|x-c|<\delta_1 $. Moreover, since $g(x)\to \infty $, when $x\to c$, there is $0<\delta <\delta _1$ s.t. $$g(x)\geq \frac{2M}{L},$$
if $|x-c|<\delta $. In particular, if $|x-c|<\delta $, we have $$f(x)g(x)\geq M,$$
and thus $f(x)g(x)\to \infty $ whenever $x\to c$.